# Are the benefits of OData lost if using a Stored Procedure in the service?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, ado.net, odata, asp.net-web-api

At the present time, our database team only allows connections to data to be done through a stored procedure.  I think the main reason for this is so they can understand the impact of a schema change if needed.  As I consider using OData for our services, this raises questions for me.  I'm curious if I lose the benefits of Odata querying/filtering if we use stored procedures underneath the covers?  My initial thought is that we'd have to tear apart the OData query and pass the specific parameters into the stored procedure.  Am I missing a key concept?  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  Did you end up using ODataQueryOptions?  Could you post a sample of how you implemented this?

Comment: Also, do you know if using a 'View" would get past the limitations of stored procedures?  So move your code into a "View" and then the odata framework can run additional queries on top of that created view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to use OData without IQueryable, you will make your life much harder. For example, Web API method with OData v4 support with IQueryable:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Product> Get()
{
    return db.Products;
}
```

See how easy it is. Otherwise you will have to deal with [ODataQueryOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odataqueryoptions(v=vs.118).aspx) directly.